# Are php scripts and memory allocation handled diffently when run from a CRON job?

Tags: php, cron

I have a php script running from a CRON job which is throwing a memory error.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 7081367 bytes) in
>   /home/nclos2/public_html/testing/larrygoins/blaster/php_mail/class.phpmailer.php
>   on line 2174

The PHP.INI has a memory allocation of 256M and this script runs without problem in the browser.

There is a loop in the script which creates attachements and then emails them.

```
While ($x = $y->fetch()){
//make the attachments
    email_it();
}

function email_it(){
// I am using PHPMailer class
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
// do all the usual stuff
    $mail->addAttachment(....);
    $mail->send();
}
```

If i loop 49 times is this creating 49 different instances causing my memory problem or is it overwriting it each time?

Comment: Yes. Most likely you're on a shared hosting environment, and by default you're probably allocated 64M. You need to adjust the available memory to something more reasonable for such a large scrip - such as 256M. Then again, if yo'ure on a shared hosting environment, it's just a matter of time before your host suspends you and advises you can't run a 15 min cron job on that environment and you'll need to upgrade to a different hosting package if you need it.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the hosting company. Perhaps they enable one a bit more freedom for a web page than a cron script. read the small print. anyway - any possibility of reducing the memory footprint?

Comment: @Ed Heal. My phpmailer class seems to be the cause. The script loops and each time a new document is created it creates a $mail = new PHPMailer and loads it up with the attachments and body text. I thought this was overwriting it each time, but I am new to objects, so maybe it is creating 49 instances and consuming all the memory?

Comment: @SmithSmithy - The garbage (god I hate American words) collector should free the memory unless something in that object or yourself is holding onto something. Perhaps a circular reference somewhere

Answer (score 0):

In most systems, PHP run via the command line uses a different `php.ini` file, which might well have different settings. If you do `php -i | grep php.ini` it should tell you which file is being used.